# LA Universal Studios in Christmas

Tags: los-angeles, universal-studios

I was planning to go to universal studios within the Christmas week
I can only find regular ticket - no fast pass.
will it be too crowded so that it'd be annoying ?

Comment: Define 'too crowded' and explain in objective terms what would be annoying for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. It will absolutely be crowded Christmas week as it is one of the busiest weeks of the year if not *the* busiest week of the year. According to [IsItPacked.com](https://www.isitpacked.com/crowd-calendars/universal-studios-hollywood/), crowd levels range from "Yup, It's Packed" (40-60 minute average wait times) to "Forget About It" (60-90 minute average wait times).
2. There is no fast pass system at Universal Studios. **However**, instead of purchasing a General Admission ticket, you can purchase a ticket called "Universal Express" that grants you express access to each ride a single time. This costs between $179-$279 depending on the date (expect to pay in the upper range for Christmas week).

Comment: what about single pass rider